# Convert char * to uint16 and uint32

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in C++. I am having some trouble getting the SQL results out of the char array into my struct.

```
class Row {
    public:
        uint8_t type;
        uint16_t user;
        uint32_t ipAddress;
        std::string name;
};

void SqlToRow(char **argv, Row *row){
    row->type = *(argv[0]);
    row->user = *(uint16_t*)argv[1];
    row->ipAddress = *(uint32_t*)argv[2];
    row->name = argv[3];
}
```

The only ones that are working is `type` and `name`. The rest look like random values like 892486210

Comment: Have you ever actually used `char` pointers in C++ before? And what sense does it make to represent a user or an IP address as one integer number (unless those are meant to be something like foreign keys)?

Comment: It would help to see the call to SqlToRow(), to know what is being passed.

Comment: @Christian Hackl What do either of your questions contribute to a solution?

Comment: @ICU_: Thanks for asking. The first question determines whether or not to start explaining the basic concept of `char*`. The second question helps in guessing what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: #1 Yes, when I have to talk to C stuff. Usually they are not double pointers. #2 IP addresses are useful as unsigned ints when they actually need to be used in networking.

Comment: @ICU_: "*IP addresses are useful as unsigned ints*" - only IPv4 addresses are, as they are 4 bytes which can fit in a single integer.  IPv6 addresses are 16 bytes, and no modern compiler has a native 128-bit numeric type available (if anything, an IPv6 address is an array of 8 2-byte integers instead).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then it's a good thing we live in an ipv4 world :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you are trying to re-interpret `char*` values as numerics. Use `sscanf` with `SCNu16` and `SCNu32`, like this:

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%" SCNu16, &row->user);
sscanf(argv[2], "%" SCNu32, &row-> ipAddress);
```

Comment: I accepted the answer but I don't have access to those macros. I used `ul` for 32, not sure what to use for 16.

Comment: - i Used "%u" and "%hu"

Comment: @ICU_ These macros should be available in [`cinttypes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes) header.